# Tablet vs handset orientation restriction

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait

I'am developing a flexible app, with *fragments*. I only want land mode on tablets, and portrait on handsets. How do I restrict the portrait only for **handset** and **landscape** only for tablets?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use your values folder's `bools.xml` in `res/values` for **handset** and `res/values-sw600dp` for **tablet**.

So you need to create those values folders in your folder and each of them must have bools.xml.

inside the bools.xml you must have a boolean for checking if it is handset or tablet device

inside **bools.xml** in `res/values`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portraitMode">true</bool>
</resources>
```

and **bools.xml** in `res/values-sw600dp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <bool name="portraitMode">false</bool>
    </resources>
```

Now you need to do orientation programatically through getting the boolean value first to check if it is a handset or tablet and use the `setRequestedOrientation` for specifying the orientation of the device

**sample:**

in the onCreate method

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portraitMode)){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```